# How to get the country from shipping address in a view?

Tags: views, commerce

I am using Drupal Commerce Kickstart!
I want to get 'Only' the country name from the shipping information of a particular order in a view,
The shipping information field in my view shows the entire shipping address including the country at last, is there a way that I can extract only the country name from that? or a db query using the order_id?

Comment: any one who could answer this please?

Answer (score 2):

Implying that you have the **Order ID** in your view:

1. Add a relationship to **Commerce Order: Referenced customer profile**, for the shipping address (Relate this entity to the customer profile referenced by its commerce_customer_shipping value)
2. Add field for **Commerce Customer profile: Address - Country**

My output after those steps:

```
Order ID: 4
Bulgaria

Order ID: 5
United States
```

FYI the data is located in **field_data_commerce_customer_address** table **commerce_customer_address_country** column.

Comment: Hello Victor, Thanks for the response.
But this didn't work either, the country failed to display but the full address did.
I wrote a db query to get the results out of it. Ill right it down.

Comment: Hey **DropDragon**, are you sure that you select the right data field? I'm positive that this Views set up http://imgur.com/yoSzvNG displays the output in my answer.

Comment: Yes I am sure I did it.
but as posted before this doesn't show me the country name, but the replacement pattern works only for the full address
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I did it by sending a DB query to get the address of a customer by an order id.

```
SELECT field_data_commerce_customer_address.commerce_customer_address_country as country
                FROM field_data_commerce_customer_address
                INNER JOIN field_data_commerce_customer_shipping
                ON field_data_commerce_customer_address.entity_id = field_data_commerce_customer_shipping.commerce_customer_shipping_profile_id
                WHERE field_data_commerce_customer_shipping.entity_id ='".$order_id."'"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can isolate the country field by enabling aggregation. Add address to your result set and group the results by the country field.